# Set of diameter < 1 is contained in a disc of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

Tags: discrete-geometry

Exercise from Matousek Lectures in Discrete Geometry

Prove that each set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of diameter at most 1 (i.e., any two points have distance at most 1) is contained in some disc of radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$

I'm just interested in the proof for 3 points. I wanted to argue that we take one point and then set the next point a unit distance anyway and then see what constraints this produces on the third point. But that doesn't consider cases where the distance between $p_1, p_2 < 1$

Comment: Is $X$ finite ?

Answer (score 3):

I would go through [Helly's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly's_theorem). For any $P\in X$, let $\Gamma_P$ a circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ and centre at $P$. For any $P,Q\in X$ we have that $\Gamma_P\cap\Gamma_Q\neq\emptyset$. If we enlarge the radii of such disks, we have that for any $P,Q,R\in X$ the disks centered at $P,Q,R$ with radii $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ intersect somewhere. By Helly's theorem, there is a point at a distance $\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ from every point of $X$.

Comment: This is approximately what I have for part b where I generalise it to all finite sets. I think I need to elaborate on the step where you go from radius $\frac{1}{2}$ to radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$